# vertical tilting simple rectangle on canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

currently im programming a classic game. I will change the perspective from a rectangle.

How i can create a vertical tilting like this?

[image]

For example, currently only using simple Rectangles, see this fiddle:

```js
var _canvas = document.getElementById('game');
var _context = _canvas.getContext('2d');
_canvas.width = 800;
_canvas.height = 500;

function getWidth() {
 return _canvas.width;
}

function getHeight() {
 return _canvas.height;
}

function drawGameField() {
  _context.save();
  
  var width   = 578;
  var height   = 538;
  var background  = _context.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 170);
  
  background.addColorStop(0, '#FFFF80');
  background.addColorStop(1, '#FDFDAD');
  
  // Background
  _context.fillStyle = background;
  _context.fillRect((getWidth() / 2) - (width / 2), (getHeight() / 2) - (height / 2), width, height);
  
  // Outer Border
  _context.beginPath();
  _context.lineWidth  = '6';
  _context.strokeStyle = '#FF0000';
  _context.rect((getWidth() / 2) - (width / 2), (getHeight() / 2) - (height / 2), width, height); 
  _context.stroke();
  
  // Inner Border
  _context.beginPath();
  width -= 25;
  height -= 25;
  _context.lineWidth  = '2';
  _context.strokeStyle = '#000000';
  _context.rect((getWidth() / 2) - (width / 2), (getHeight() / 2) - (height / 2), width, height); 
  _context.stroke();
  
  // Fields
  var fields = [
   [ 230, 39 ],
   [ 272, 39 ],
   [ 315, 39 ],
   [ 315, 81 ],
   [ 315, 124 ],
   [ 315, 167 ],
   [ 315, 210 ],
   [ 358, 210 ],
   [ 401, 210 ],
   [ 444, 210 ],
   [ 486, 210 ],
   [ 486, 252 ],
   [ 486, 295 ],
   [ 444, 295 ],
   [ 401, 295 ],
   [ 358, 295 ],
   [ 315, 295 ],
   [ 315, 338 ],
   [ 315, 381 ],
   [ 315, 424 ],
   [ 315, 466 ],
   [ 272, 466 ],
   [ 230, 466 ],
   [ 230, 424 ],
   [ 230, 381 ],
   [ 230, 338 ],
   [ 230, 295 ],
   [ 187, 295 ],
   [ 144, 295 ],
   [ 101, 295 ],
   [ 59, 295 ],
   [ 59, 252 ],
   [ 59, 210 ],
   [ 101, 210 ],
   [ 144, 210 ],
   [ 187, 210 ],
   [ 230, 210 ],
   [ 230, 167 ],
   [ 230, 124 ],
   [ 230, 81 ]
  ];
  for(var index in fields) {
   var field = fields[index];
   drawField(field[0] + 130, field[1] + 10);
  }
}

function drawField(x, y) {
  _context.fillStyle  = '#FFFFFF';
  _context.beginPath();
  _context.arc(x, y, 16, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  _context.lineWidth  = 4;
  _context.strokeStyle = '#000000';
  _context.stroke();
  _context.closePath();
  _context.fill(); 
}

drawGameField();
```

```css
canvas {
  width: 800px;
  height: 500px;
  background: #DDDDDD;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="game" width="800" height="500"></canvas>
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/343vab0w/)

Comment: @markE your duplicate mark is helpful. not. See the difference, on the duplicate will using images with `drawImage` with some parameters. Do you think im using a image for tilting?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. :-) To answer your question directly: **Html5 canvas cannot transform a rectangle into a trapezoid.** Any drawings (images or not ) simply cannot be transformed into the trapezoid you desire.  That's because canvas only only has Affine Transformation capabilities (only create parallelograms) -- so, *natively*, it can't disproportionally transform a rectangle into a trapezoid. Please look again at the duplicate answers for workarounds to canvas's native limitation.  Both answers offer help in this regard. Try these techniques and post another question if you have issues